# how to match datetime column by passing date only in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table, where there is a datetime Column, I want to match this column by passing only date & datetime column is heaving date & time both (i.e 25/06/2013 4:54:12 PM).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use CAST and CONVERT functions for converting date
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx

For example

```
select * 
from datetimetable 
where convert(char(10), datetimecolumn, 103) = '25/12/2013'
```

BUT remember, that this code is for testing purposes only.
I recommend you to play with different parameters of CONVERT function
in order to better understand it (and to play with different sizes of the first parameter)

please, view solutions in the other answers on your question to find out the best one for your environment

Comment: consider that `convert` is going to kneel down your server if table is big.

Comment: Yikes, this forces a scan. Also [varchar without length is a lazy and dangerous habit](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

It's usually best in this situation to leave the column alone and do some manipulation on your parameter. So if you're passing a `@SearchDate` parameter, I'd do:

```
SELECT abc from mytable
where
   datetimecolumn >= @SearchDate and
   datetimecolumn < DATEADD(day,1,@SearchDate)
```

I *believe* that, if you're running on SQL Server 2008 or later, and use the following:

```
SELECT abc from mytable
where
   CAST(datetimecolumn as date) = @SearchDate
```

That an index on `datetimecolumn` can be used. Whereas I'm *certain* that an index is usable given my first query. You should, in general, be wary of calling functions on columns - such actions can often cripple performance by forcing a full table scan.

And unlike you're accepted answer, I would *always* seek to avoid treating dates as strings - as soon as you do, you're inviting all kinds of issues around formatting.

Comment: +1 This is the only exception where conversion of the column still yields a seek, but you're right to question it - I'm not sure if that will always work today, never mind that it will work tomorrow, next version, etc. Undocumented = not guaranteed = be cautious.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I included it because I'm sure you (or one of the other experts) have told me off about it before :-)

Answer (score 0):

datetime format in t-sql is a little tricky, first of all you need to be aware of date time (i.e 25/06/2013 4:54:12 PM) is greater than 25/06/2013 , so you need to use > and < operators, for ![enter image description here][1]example orderdate > '20130625' AND orderdate < '20130626' , sql server considers 'YYYYMMDD' as global datetime format and it is language independent. take a look at the attachement...

Answer (score 0):

try -:

```
DECLARE @givenDate DATE;

DECLARE @t AS TABLE (
    fld_DateTime DATETIME
)

SET @givenDate = '2013-04-24'

INSERT INTO @t ( fld_DateTime ) 
VALUES ('2013-04-23 14:37:59.580')
, ('2013-04-23 14:59:02.403')
, ('2013-04-23 15:15:36.890')
, ('2013-04-24 08:57:45.800')
, ('2013-04-24 10:44:56.663')
, ('2013-04-24 13:18:20.760')
, ('2013-04-25 09:38:55.503')
, ('2013-06-28 09:20:11.007')
, ('2013-06-28 12:37:04.973')
, ('2013-06-28 12:38:50.130')
, ('2013-07-03 15:27:36.167')

SELECT fld_DateTime
FROM @t
WHERE fld_DateTime >= @givenDate AND fld_DateTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @givenDate)
```